# eclipse debugging shows source files with wrong line numbers

Tags: eclipse, debugging

when I click F3 and drill down into a method definition, eclipse goes into a dependency jar.  ----- first question: where did it get the source file? I don't see the jars containing actual source files, did it decompile ? ---- I set a breakpoint, and run debug.

but the debugging process never seems to land on the correct breakpoint, and the breakpoint I set is rarely executed. it turns out that the source code shown is wrong, so that the breakpoint is set at wrong locations too.

here is what I see from eclipse window:

```
/*     */   public <T> T execute(URI url, HttpMethod method, RequestCallback requestCallback, ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor)
/*     */     throws RestClientException
/*     */   {
/* 415 */     return doExecute(url, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
/*     */   }`
```

the comment before each line seems to show the correct line number, but they do not match up with their true line number shown on the left of the eclipse window frame. i.e. the above code segment occupies lines 315--319 in the window, not 415.

so how can I grab the correct sources and display them in my debugging process? do I have to manually grab all the jars ? is there a way to specify in my pom file?

thanks
Yang

Answer (score 7):

Because I didn't find the solution when I googled it and this is the first search result, I want to share how I solved this issue.

1. In Eclipse, ensure that `Project > Build Automatically` is checked;
2. Right click in your project and go `to Build Path > Configure Build Path...`
3. Check the tabs for errors (missing dependencies, sources not found, etc), fix/delete them and press OK.
4. In Eclipse, go to `Project > Clean...`, select your project and press OK;

If you get errors at step #3 (like Access denied or similar), go to the root folder of your project and look for a file called `.classpath`. Edit the file and manually fix/remove the block that is causing the error.

This also solves when Eclipse doesn't display error icons in classes with compilation errors.

Answer (score 6):

In Eclipse, you can specify the sources for debugging under Run -> Debug Configurations. Select your Debug configuration from the list and configure the Source lookup path in the 'Source' tab

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it happed because I had multiple version of the same dependency in my `.m2`. So I solved it by deleting unnecessary versions.

default location would be -
`C:\Users\[username]\.m2\repository`